# Two Column Bootstrap Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have two groups, A & B. On mobile view, A sidebar will stack on top of A content. Likewise for group B. However, I'm encountering two issues w/ my two column Bootstrap layout.

Issue #1
On mobile view, Content A get's stuck behind Sidebar B. I've tried adding float classes and clearing the floats, z-index, positioning, etc., and I'm just unable to get them to stack A,B,A,B =/

Issue #2
...is that I do want the max-height to be 100%, but what I'm getting is 100% height just for group A. What methods could I use to get both groups A & B to fit (together) 100% on the page?

My code is as follows; I appreciate any and all help! Thanks a ton.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 a">
      Sidebar content A
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
      Body content A
  </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end col-sm-12 -->
</div> <!-- end container-fluid -->

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 b">
      Sidebar content B
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
      Body content B
  </div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end col-sm-12 -->
</div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
```

CSS

```
html,body,.col-sm-12,.container-fluid, .row {
  height:100%;
}
.row > div {
  height:100%;
}
.a, .b {
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielwmaldonado/o02m79co/)

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add

```
col-xs-12
```

to your divs to stop the weird overlap- so your html would read

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 a">
  Sidebar content A
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
  Body content A
</div>
```

Regarding the height issue you can apply a new class to your rows and update your css as follows:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
  height: 50%;
}
.col-sm-12,
.fullheight {
  height: 100%;
}
.a,
.b {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row fullheight">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 fullheight a">Sidebar content A</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 fullheight">Body content A</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end col-sm-12 -->
</div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row fullheight">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 fullheight b">Sidebar content B</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 fullheight">Body content B</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end col-sm-12 -->
</div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @anniemac that fix'd it right up!

Comment: Does that resolve your 100% height issue too - I wasn't quite following that bit - let me know if you need something more!

Comment: unfortunately, it does not. If you have any insight into what I'm missing there, that'd be great too!

Comment: is it that you want the two to sit side by side on the collapsed view so
    a header  |  b header
    a content  | b content 
?

Comment: adding the col-xs-12 fixed exactly what I needed. so that's perfect. thanks so much...

on desktop view, i want all columns to fit within the browser window, so total - height:100%;

as of right now, however, group A is a total height of 100%. i'm wanting more of 50/50. does that make sense?

Comment: sorry @AnnieMac -- still learning the ropes here and pressed return before i was done... the col-xs-12 is great... still need some help w/ the height of the columns... i want both A & B columns to be visible in desktop @ 100%. the way i have it, however, it's only group A that is 100%... does that make sense? thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry for the wait- just updated my answer - I think that resolves it (definitely for the desktop view) - you might be better to use media queries to then achieve the look you want on mobile if the div heights aren't appropriate

Comment: that works perfectly! thank you so much for your help... i'm definately more experienced w/ media queries than boostrap which i'll use to modify my content - but for the structure this is exactly what i needed. again, thank you! i have a much better idea of the differences :thumbsup: